# Elasticsearch routing to same nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster of 4 nodes with 2 shards in each node (same hardware all of them), I don't have any dedicated master, client or data nodes. Then I have a 200 servers that send documents to this cluster using the TransporClient in a Java application (I'm adding the four nodes in there), I was expecting that all the nodes would get the same amount of bulk request, but I can see that always there are 2 nodes with a significant higher volume of bulk requests.

According to Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html) since I didn't change the routing field, this should be the _id field which in my case is generated by Elasticsearch, so all the nodes should get same amount of bulk requests. Am I missing anything? Does a master node get less requests?

Comment: The document you're referring to is about routing for **shards** (i.e. within a node) not nodes. Can you share how your Java application TransportClient is configured and also a summary of your cluster configuration?

Comment: I know that's for shards, but that was the only thing I could think about, I have 2 shards in each node, so I still think it should be more balanced. For the TransportClient I'm not doing anything special, just adding the four nodes in the client, so it should communicate with them in round robin fashion.

Comment: How do you witness that only two nodes are getting most of the requests and not the others?

Comment: I use the following url: myserver:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v there I can monitor how many active bulk request are there, also how many queued.